# How to replace the backflow preventer in an old house?

Tags: backflow-preventer

My house is about 30 years old. The backflow preventer in my front yard looks old as well. One time, a person who did our lawn carelessly cut the 2 pipes (where two red arrows point) of the backflow preventer with a weed eater. As a fix, he placed 2 coupler. I'm hoping to replace the two valves of the backflow preventer and the white pipes (but reuse febco 765). Do I need a key to shut off the city water for this? How do I do this job?

P.S. I've looked on Youtube for a good video for replacing the whole backflow preventer. If you know of a good instructional video please include it in your reply, appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Most plumbing only requires two wrenches and a shutoff valve.  You have two shut off valves there(blue).  You should also have a shut off valve inside the house.  Depending how much you want to replace.  Just the back flow, then the inlet shut off turned off.

Comment: 30 year old house? Barely broken in

Comment: That's the problem with Americans (and I'm one of them) - they think 30 is "old"... When you're looking at a church that was started in 800AD, now you're talking _old_. Heck, by the OP's standards, my marriage is positively _ancient_! >:( **Also** there should be a valve inside the house that will shut off water flow to this outside spigot without having to shut off the whole house. Turn that off, make your repairs, turn it back on.